# How to validate forms inside vuetify stepper using vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I am trying to validate the form inside the stepper component of `vuetify`. I have managed somehow to do the validation. But i am confused whether this is the good way for doing the validation on vuetify stepper.

I am using the same number of method as the number of step in the wizard. I am using `vee-validate` for the validation with the scope.

```javascript
  methods: {
    submitForm1(scope) {
      debugger;
      this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.e1 = 2;
        }
      });
    },
    submitForm2(scope) {
      debugger;
      this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.e1 = 3;
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

Data:

```javascript
  data() {
    return {
      e1: 0,
      name: "",
      resultStep1: true
    };
  }
```

**Vuetify Stepper:** Form1

```html
<v-stepper-content step="1">
    <form data-vv-scope="form1">
        <v-card color="lighten-1" class="mb-5" height="200px">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-text-field 
                v-model="name" label="Contract Type" 
                :counter="10" 
                :error-messages="errors.collect('name')" 
                v-validate="'required|max:10'" 
                data-vv-name="name" required data-vv-scope="form1">
            </v-text-field>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
        <v-btn color="secondary" @click.native="submitForm1('form1')">Next</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Cancel</v-btn>
    </form>    
</v-stepper-content>
```

**Form 2:**

```html
<v-stepper-content step="2">
    <form data-vv-scope="form2">
        <v-card color="lighten-1" class="mb-5" height="200px">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-text-field 
                v-model="email" label="Contract Email" 
                :counter="10" 
                :error-messages="errors.collect('email')" 
                v-validate="'required|max:10'" 
                data-vv-name="email" required data-vv-scope="form2">
            </v-text-field>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
        <v-btn color="secondary" @click.native="submitForm2('form2')">Next</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Cancel</v-btn>
    </form>   
</v-stepper-content>
```

It seems it will be hard to manage the forms and validation if the step increases, with the way by which I am implementing. Because i need to add the number of method with the number of steps.

Also, please suggest me if i wanted to have a button for making the form back. How should i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `e1` is your v-model for stepper :

I think you can factorise your `submitForm` function, like this :

```
methods: {
  submitForm(scope) {
    debugger;
    this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.e1++;
      }
    });
  },
  goBack(){
    this.e1--
  }
}
```

Just call it like this in your html :

```
@click.native="submitForm('yourFormScopeName')"
```

And you can bind `goBack` method on an other button or wathever you want

Comment: I have done everything on this to make work, but you show me the right direction. I will accept this as answer. when i will fully integrate on my code.

Comment: yeah I have integrated this and it seems it is working as per my requirement. thanks for the help.